# Android adb is unable to find Teclast G18 tpad for on mac os

Tags: android, adb, mobile-devices

Android adb can't detect Telcast G18 tpad for mac os. I've run

```
adb kill-server
```

to stop the adb daemon and run

```
adb start-server
```

to restart the adb daemon. But still failed to make adb recognize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-porting/eakpeYmFUro) on the google group, I am trying to modify the adb_usb.ini file by appending the correspondance device usb vendor id.

But how can I know which usb vendor id should I use? Fortunately, I managed to google a list of vendors for usb drivers [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/freebsd/head/sys/dev/usb/usbdevs), in which case here, the usb device vendor id is:

> vendor TECLAST        0x071b  Teclast

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem with Teclast P79HD tablet PC built on Intel CPU. My Windows7 desktop detected the tablet which was connect via USB as an unknown USB device and I could not update its driver. The only program that helped me to revive the tablet was Adb_Run_v.3.78.65 by Vitaly Shipilov. You can download this program anywhere in the Internet. It's free.

You should act in the following way:

1. Install Adb_Run_v.3.78.65 on your Windows desktop.
2. Restart your PC.
3. Click Adb Run icon to start the program, then exit from the program. You should start it to start adb server. After that you will see adb.exe process via the Task Manager.
4. Go to Setting of your tablet, then Storage -> USB computer connection (additional settings) and check 'Media device (MTP)' in 'Connect as' section. Then connect your tablet to PC via USB cable.

After that your PC will detect the tablet as Media device (MTP). You will see the unit in the Device Manager as Android Phone. Now you can transfer files but you cannot use the tablet in debug mode when USB is connected. To resolve this problem you should act as it is described on the page: 
[Configuring Your Android* USB Debug Connection](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/configuring-your-windows-usb-android-debug-connection-for-the-intel-xdk?language=es#Windows_USB)
See the second half of this article 'To install the Android USB debug driver on Windows 7, 8 or 10'. The driver which helped in my case was 'Android Composite ADB Interface v.4.0.0.0 [23.05.2014]' by Google, Inc. And I checked 'Camera (PTP)' in 'USB computer connection' instead of 'Media device (MTP)'. After this procedure Android Studio began detecting my tablet right and I was able to use it in debug mode.